RoadRunner - context deadline exceeded
Interactive debugging (Docker + XDebug + RoadRunner in VSCode) started well, but after 10 - 20 seconds stopped with error:
worker_exec_with_timeout: ExecTTL: context deadline exceeded

Guess it's RR configuration issue.
Current rr.yaml is:
version: "3"

rpc:
  listen: tcp://127.0.0.1:6001

server:
  command: "php worker.php"
  env:
    - XDEBUG_SESSION: "1"

http:
  address: "0.0.0.0:8100"
  pool:
    num_workers: 1
    debug: true
    supervisor:
      idle_ttl: "0s"
      exec_ttl: "0s"

RR started via supervisor as:
/usr/bin/php -d variables_order=EGPCS /var/www/html/artisan octane:start --server=roadrunner --host=0.0.0.0 --rpc-port=6001 --port=8100

How to beat context deadline exceeded error?

Your configuration is incorrect: do not use supervisor in the debug mode, because you have 0 workers in it. Your num_workers configuration option is ignored. Workers in debug mode are allocated per request.
Docs about debug mode: https://docs.roadrunner.dev/docs/php-worker/developer#debug-mode
Docs about debugging with XDEBUG is here: https://docs.roadrunner.dev/docs/php-worker/debugging

Even to drop supervisor section - nothing changed, debug with RR works just about 10-20 seconds

10 seconds is a RR timeout when PHP worker hangs (context deadline error). That means, your script hangs, or you have more connections which XDEBUG expects to have. You may try to temporarily omit octane and use just RR + simple worker to find the problem.
